# Фигура в wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf

[image]

Как я могу сделать такую фигуру в wpf?

Comment: Вставьте image.

Comment: Я поставил фотографию

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что вопросы-картинки без словесного описания бесполезны для базы знаний

Answer (score 4):

```
<Image Source="myPhoto.jpg" />
```

Comment: `<img src=myphoto.jpg`>